# PNG UIImage with transparency loosing alpha after GPUImageBrightnessFilter

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, gpuimage

I'm trying to manipulate an UIImage brightness with GPUImageBrightnessFilter with the following code.

```
GPUImagePicture *source = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:_imgMask smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
GPUImageBrightnessFilter *brightness = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];

[source addTarget: brightness];
[brightness addTarget:GPUImageView];

[source processImage];
```

But the output image is generated without the original transparency. Am I missing something to generate the output image with the original transparency?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, `GPUImagePicture` does not support an alpha channel when translated back to a UIImage.

You could, however, display the native `GPUImagePicture` in a `GPUImageView` - setting the `backgroundColor` property of the imageView to `[UIColor clearColor]`.

See [this](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/706) ticket for more info.